# String length in the type

Tags: javascript, special-characters, flowtype

I have a a need to create a type that is a single character.

```
type Symbol = string
```

However I am not able to do this. The closest I got was doing:

```
const CHARS = { a: 1, b: 1, c: 1 /*, and so on */ } 
type Symbol = $Keys<typeof CHARS>;
```

`CHARS` is an object where `keys` are every single character on the keyboard, then I make an enum out of it. This is not good though, because it doesn't accommodate all chars, like on foreign keyboards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to describe in Flow the type of strings of length 1.

But a "single character" probably isn't what you want anyway. At least not in a precise sense. In JavaScript, a String "character" actually means a UTF-16 codepoint. Many codepoints are not printable or only make sense as a modifier to another character. Some "characters" (e.g. a pile of poo, ) are actually considered 2 characters in Javascript. A less silly example is `\u0061\u0332` which displays as `"a̲"`. If you try to handle this properly, you'll find yourself trying to work out how to convert a string into an array of what you're about to find out are called grapheme clusters.

I won't ramble on any more about this because you almost certainly didn't ask this question to read about character encodings. My point is, even if you were able to define the type you wanted, it's not precisely correct anyway. Even forgetting Unicode, did you really want `"\r"` or a vertical tab to be valid values?

Given that you'd be allowing invalid values anyway, the best solution is probably to ignore the length and write validation where needed. Alternatively it actually wouldn't be *too* onerous to create an enum with a list of the <100 values you actually want:

```
enum Symbol = 'A' | 'B' | 'C' | 'D' ....
```

Comment: Thank you Peter for such an indepth reply! I love the example hahaha! The encoding speech was very informative I really appreciate it and wish I could do more then +1.